# Ошибка в логах сервера на Node JS

Tags: node.js, svelte

При запуске приложения ошибок нет, и приложение нормально функционирует, но если зайти в логи сервера выходит постоянная ошибка.

Ошибка в логах:

```
2024-03-23_04:59:51.32690 Sleep 60 secs. before restart due to previous errors...
2024-03-23_05:15:46.84825 node:internal/modules/esm/assert:88
2024-03-23_05:15:46.84833         throw new ERR_IMPORT_ATTRIBUTE_MISSING(url, 'type', validType);
2024-03-23_05:15:46.84834               ^
2024-03-23_05:15:46.84835 
2024-03-23_05:15:46.84835 TypeError [ERR_IMPORT_ATTRIBUTE_MISSING]: Module "file:///home/с123123/с123123.ru/app/package.json" needs an import attribute of "type: json"
2024-03-23_05:15:46.84836     at validateAttributes (node:internal/modules/esm/assert:88:15)
2024-03-23_05:15:46.84837     at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:153:3)
2024-03-23_05:15:46.84837     at async ModuleLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:403:7)
2024-03-23_05:15:46.84838     at async ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:285:45)
2024-03-23_05:15:46.84838     at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:78:21) {
2024-03-23_05:15:46.84839   code: 'ERR_IMPORT_ATTRIBUTE_MISSING'
2024-03-23_05:15:46.84839 }
2024-03-23_05:15:46.84840 
2024-03-23_05:15:46.84841 Node.js v21.7.1
2024-03-23_05:15:48.05344 Sleep 60 secs. before restart due to previous errors...
```

сам package.json :

```
    "name": "sveltekit-gun-example",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "node server/dev/index.js",
        "build": "vite build",
        "start": "node server/index.js",
        "preview": "node server/index.js",
        "build:preview": "npm run build && npm run start",
        "test": "playwright test",
        "check": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json",
        "check:watch": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --watch",
        "lint": "prettier --plugin-search-dir . --check .",
        "format": "prettier --plugin-search-dir . --write ."
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@playwright/test": "^1.37.1",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-node": "^1.3.1",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.5.0",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.15",
        "postcss": "^8.4.29",
        "prettier": "^3.0.3",
        "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^3.0.3",
        "svelte": "^4.2.0",
        "svelte-check": "^3.5.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
        "tslib": "^2.6.2",
        "typescript": "^5.2.2"
    },
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {
        "@floating-ui/dom": "^1.5.1",
        "@sentry/sveltekit": "^7.61.1",
        "esm": "^3.2.25",
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "flowbite": "^2.0.0",
        "flowbite-svelte": "^0.44.2",
        "gun": "^0.2020.1239",
        "svelte-local-storage-store": "^0.6.0",
        "tailwind-merge": "^2.0.0",
        "unique-username-generator": "^1.2.0"
    }
}
```